# Formula for the sequence of hydrogen orbital quantum numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, atomic-physics, hydrogen, orbitals

My previous question had a poor reception because somebody thought my question was not about physics. Therefore, I repost the question in a less mathematically precise way, such that it is about physics.

I want to make a list of all the quantum numbers of the orbitals of hydrogen. You often want this in computational physics, for example if you want to use the orbitals of hydrogen as a basis, and you want to sum over the basis. In my problem, I am working on a wave function that I expect is relativity similar to the ground state of hydrogen, so the canonical way to approach the problem is to list the orbitals in an order, such that those that are most similar to the ground state comes first in the list, then those that are less similar come next, and then those that are even less similar come after that, etc...

So if I want to index the orbitals by $i = 1,2,3,4,\cdots$, there is some standard formulas that maps $i \mapsto (n,l,m)$, such that the first few indexes are least dissimilar to the ground state, for example

```
  i | (n, l, m)
----+-----------
  1 | (1, 0, 0)
  2 | (2, 0, 0)
  3 | (2, 1,-1)
  4 | (2, 1, 0)
  5 | (2, 1, 1)
etc...
```

I have seen these formulas in my computational physics class 3 years ago, but was an idiot and disposed of my notes when I moved to Cambridge. If you have the formulas that make this indexing precise, such that it can be used in a computational physics program, please provide them.

Comment: Do you mean something like the triangular diagram showing the orbital order here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/General_Chemistry/Filling_Electron_Shells

Comment: What do you mean by "least dissimilar to the ground state"? Every state other than the ground state is orthogonal to it, so they are all (by the only universal objective measure in Hilbert space) equally dissimilar to it.

Comment: Formulas for $n$, $l$, and $m$ in terms of $i$ are messy. Why are you not just looping over $n$, $l$, and $m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the index $i$, first calculate $n$ using

$${n=}\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+\frac{(-108+108i+\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3887-7776i+3888i^2})^{1/3}}{2\times 3^{2/3}}+\frac{1}{2\times 3^{1/3}(-108+108i+\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3887-7776i+3888i^2})^{1/3}}\right\rfloor.$$

Then calculate $l$ using

$$l=\left\lfloor\sqrt{i-\frac{2n^3-3n^2+n}{6}-1}\right\rfloor.$$

Finally, calculate $m$ using

$$m=i-\frac{2n^3-3n^2+n}{6}-(l^2+l+1).$$

Here $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) function, and $i$ is your index, not the square root of $-1$.

Don't believe me? Try it!

The derivation of these formulas is left as an exercise for the reader. They are derivable starting from the fact that there are $n^2$ values of $i$ corresponding to a particular $n$, and $2l+1$ values of $i$ corresponding to a particular $n$ and $l$.

But why would you want to do this when you could simply use three nested loops, iterating over

$$n=0,1,2,\dots,$$

then over

$$l=0,1,\dots,n-1,$$

then over

$$m=-l,-l+1,\dots,l-1,l,$$

instead of looping over $i$ and using these awful formulas?

ADDENDUM:

A commenter asked about the origin of the surprising integers in the formula for $n$. They come from solving the relatively unsurprising cubic equation

$$2n^3-3n^2+n+(6-6i)=0.$$

This cubic comes from considering which value of $i$ corresponds to the $(n,l,m)$ tuple $(n,0,0)$. For example $(4,0,0)$ is preceded by one tuple with $n=1$, four tuples with $n=2$, and nine tuples with $n=3$. Thus its $i$ value is $(1+4+9)+1$ or $15$. In general, we have

$$i=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2=\frac{1}{6}(2n^3-3n^2+n+6)$$

for the $(n,0,0)$ tuples.

Solving this for $n$ in terms of $i$ gives an integer value for $n$ when $i$ is the appropriate value for $(n,0,0)$ -- for example, $i=6$ gives $n=3$ and $i=15$ gives $n=4$ -- and a fractional value of $n$, with integer part $3$, for the other tuples in between $(3,0,0)$ and $(4,0,0)$ with $i$ values of $7$ through $14$. That is why we use the "floor" function to get the integer part.

I used Mathematica to solve the cubic equation, but the formula for solving cubics goes back to Cardano in 1545. For the general cubic

$$an^3+bn^2+cn+d=0,$$

Mathematica gives the relevant root as

$$-\frac{b}{3a}+\frac{(-2b^3+9abc-27a^2d+\sqrt{4(-b^2+3ac)^3+(-2b^3+9abc-27a^2d)^2})^{1/3}}{3\times 2^{1/3}a}-\frac{2^{1/3}(-b^2+3ac)}{3a(-2b^3+9abc-27a^2d+\sqrt{4(-b^2+3ac)^3+(-2b^3+9abc-27a^2d)^2})^{1/3}}.$$

This is complicated enough that substituting $a=2$, $b=-3$, $c=1$, and $d=6-6i$ gives the surprising integers.

ADDENDUM 2:

Using [Cardano's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html), you can get a much nicer and more symmetrical result for $n$ than Mathematica produces, namely:

$$n=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+\left(j+\sqrt{j^2-\frac{1}{1728}}\right)^{1/3}+\left(j-\sqrt{j^2-\frac{1}{1728}}\right)^{1/3}\right\rfloor,$$

where

$$j=\frac{3}{2}(i-1).$$ I love the fact that the one surprising integer here, 1728, is a famous number in [modular functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant). This is almost certainly just a coincidence.

Comment: Can you comment on the origin of the numerical constants here? (particularly 108, 3887, 3888 and 7776.) I mean, for the benefit of those of us who fully agree with you that nested loops are obviously a better approach and that the calculation shouldn't really be done at all, but want to understand the structural origin of the complexity of this result.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I added an addendum explaining how they arise.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It was a fair guess that they came from the cubic-root formula, I guess I underestimated its complexity and its ability to invoke large numbers into its innards.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I've added a new, improved formula for $n$ that you may find amusing.